# XML Deserialization of a date with an empty value

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I'm getting a xml file from one vendor that has some "empty" dates like this:

```
<UpdatedOn/>
<DeletedOn/>
```

By doing a regular deserialization it fails with:

> Inner Exception: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any ideas how to deal with this ?

My fields are already marked for a default `DateTime`:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute(typeof(System.DateTime), "1901-01-01")]
public System.DateTime UpdateOn{...}
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the *exact* xml? That isn't (as far as I know) legal xml. You can put xml without having to escape it - either inline in back-ticks `<likeThis/>` - or just use the "code" button in the editor to indent it 4 spaces for a larger (multi-line) block of xml.

Comment: ops...sorry
...
'<UpdateOn/>'
'<DeletedOn/>'
....

Comment: Ta; fixed in question; for info - those (in your "oops...sorry..." comment) aren't back-ticks - they are single quotes; back-ticks are the slanty one: `

Answer (score 14):

I'm assuming that the xml is actually something like `<UpdatedOn/>` / `<DeletedOn/>`? i.e. empty elements.

When non-standard formats are involved, one trick that works is to introduce your own shim property:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class Foo {
    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime Bar { get; set; }

    [Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public string BarTransport {
        get {
            return Bar == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : XmlConvert.ToString(Bar);
        }
        set {
            Bar = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? DateTime.MinValue
                : XmlConvert.ToDateTime(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the `Foo.Bar` property (the actual `DateTime`) isn't used during serialization; instead, the `Foo.BarTransport` property is serialized under the `Bar` element - but with special rules. You can replace `DateTime.MinValue` with any other value that you want to treat as the blank/default.

Note that if you don't want to send the `Bar` element at all, you can write a `public bool ShouldSerializeBarTransport()`, which `XmlSerializer` will check - if you return `false`, it won't get written.

Comment: thanks Marc, it's exactly what I wanted.
The only thing I changed is the usage of another overload of XmlConvert.ToDateTime(string) as this one is obsolete.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `<UpdatedOn/>` to `<UpdatedOn xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />` and you can deserialize the XML.