# How to handle null in xml and c#

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

suppose i am trying to deserialize xml to my class and if any value is null or empty for decimal or datetime then how to handle the null.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Salary" , typeof(double))]
public string Salary { get; set; }

[XmlElement(ElementName = "BirthDate" , typeof(DateTime))]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

suppose if BirthDate or Salary is null or empty in xml then how to handle it at the time of deserialization. need solution. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options as specified here in [XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Specify a [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to specify the default value

```
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute ("0")]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Salary" , typeof(double))]
public string Salary { get; set; }

[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute ("02-May-2011")]
[XmlElement(ElementName = "BirthDate" , typeof(datetime))]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

`Another option is to use a special pattern to create a Boolean field recognized by the XmlSerializer, and to apply the XmlIgnoreAttribute to the field. The pattern is created in the form of propertyNameSpecified. For example, if there is a field named "MyFirstName" you would also create a field named "MyFirstNameSpecified" that instructs the XmlSerializer whether or not to generate the XML element named "MyFirstName".`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of **Nullabe** type will resolve issue easily.

Comment: @user728750 - like this public Nullable<Int32> Bar { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Replace "double" with it's nullable type equivalent "double?" should do it. Then simply deal with the lack of a value in your object.

Alternatively you can implement a shim property:

[XML Deserialization of a date with an empty value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838246/xml-deserialization-of-a-date-with-an-empty-value)

Comment: what is shim property. discuss in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Enterprise Library validation application block. Or simply change the type to Nullable.