# Deserializing with empty dates in xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I've recently sorted my xsd with to allow the xml data to have empty string in date fields. I used simpleType and union to allow this:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="EmptyDate">
  <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:date emptystring" />
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="emptystring">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="" />
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

However, even though the XML File allows this, when i go to deserialize, it comes up with an error saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. Currently, this is how I am deserializing:

```
xml_path = xml_dir + file_name;
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Families));
Families fam;
using (XmlReader read = XmlReader.Create(xml_path))
{
    fam = (Families)x.Deserialize(read);
}
```

When i debugged the code, it threw an error at the bottom line of code that deserializes.

Is there any way of manipulating the c# code so that it allows for empty dates to be passed through

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838246/xml-deserialization-of-a-date-with-an-empty-value ?

Comment: I have looked into that article but didn't provide my situation with a solution. I tried what they had on there, but it kept coming up with the same error.

Comment: Rather than supporting an empty string for a `DateTime`, consider allowing it to be nullable: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2010/03/22/how-to-get-minoccurs-0-in-the-schema-for-xmlserializer-struct-members.aspx

Comment: Can you share a sample c# class that reproduces a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem?

Comment: @dbc while that would be a good solution, unfortunately, the data I get from clients is about 120,000 + lines of xml data. All the empty date fields will be represented as <thisDate></thisDate>, so essentially as an empty string. It would be too much of a hassle to go through the entire document and change the values to <thisDate xsi:nil=true></thisDate>

Comment: Right then.  In that case, can you share an example class, to speed the process up?

Comment: lol. when i changed my xsd, i forgot to update the class. I feel really stupid now haha. But as soon as I updated my class, the file started deserializing. If you hadn't have told me to provide an example class, i wouldn't have even realized. 

Thanks :)